# Python Boolean Mapping

Tags: python-3.x, boolean

How would I go about mapping two `sets`, one `boolean`, one `string`.

In the case of my program the `batsmanName` list is empty and two strings are inserted in position `[0]` and `[1]` at the beginning of the program (user chosen name).

Now there's a calculation in another function that sets the state of `batsmanBatting` in `[0]` or `[1]` to either true or false depending on whether or not the runs are odd or even. Basically if `batsmanBatting` index is `true`, then it needs to display the `batsmanName` in the corresponding index.

```
batsmanName=[]
batsmanRun=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
batsmanOnField=[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]
batsmanBatting=[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]
```

Am I on the right path with this: `bat=dict(zip(batsmanName, batsmanBatting)`

Any help would be much appreciated guys

Comment: What does "display the batsmanName in the corresponding index" mean?

Comment: well its an empty list when program begins user will enter to names that'll go in index [0] and [1] the same indexs in lists batsmanRun, batsmanOnField and batsmanBatting should be mapped to the batsmanName. and as stated the index in batsmanName [2], [3], [4], [5].. etc etc will be entered in sequence later in the game if one of the players in [0] or [1] get out

Comment: OK, so to add the name to the list you use, as mentioned previously, `batsmanName.append(thename)`. And to indicate what batsman is batting in round x, you do `batsmanBatting[x] = n`, where n would be the index of the current batsman. Judging from your code, you already know this. Which is why I'm confused by your question. You need to be more exact in your questions. Explain what you want to do, show the code that you are using to do that and explain in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks lennart, yeah I know I've only just been doing python for bout 4 weeks now (first time to program anything) and my lecturer threw me in the deep end with this assignment. I'll try to be a bit more precise with my Q's

Answer (score 0):

i think u are on the right track, but batsmanName list must not be empty when the **bat** function is called, otherwise the dictionary will be empty because there will be no key against the values.

Comment: it has 2 values in it, names of players entered by the user at the beginning of the program. if a player is struck out it'll prompt the user to add a 3rd element to the batsmanName list and this continues on until 10 players are out

Comment: do you want to change the batting order during the game ?? or the batting order is fixed while user enter the players' name ?

Comment: there's two batters on the field at one time if one player hits a even number he remains the active batter, if he hits an uneven number it switches to the other player. In case of order it must remain in the order the user inputs, for instance the first two players will be in index [0] and [1] and the others will be entered as the game goes on and a batter gets striked out then the user will be prompted to enter a thrid batter